# Django refusing to serve NEWLY ADDED static files

Tags: python, django, static

### The problem

Django is acting weird. I built a website a month ago. I have a static/img folder in my app, with a bunch of logos and images in it. I refer to them with

```
<img src="{% static 'img/logo-elephant.png' %}">
```

And it works.
However, I added a new file to the very same folder, and when I refer to it,

```
<img src="{% static 'img/white-logo.png' %}">
```

**it gives me a 404 error.**
I am completely stumped. Its like newly added files are invisible to Django. Even if I copy an existing file and rename it to something, it raises a 404 error.

### Stuff I already tried

- Printing the STATIC_ROOT to make sure it's pointing to the static folder of my app. It is.
- Running `collectstatic`. Though it shouldn't make a difference, this is a development server, but I ran it just for good measure.

Comment: Did you put the file in `STATIC_ROOT` directory or did you put it in an app or `STATICFILES_DIRS` directory?

Comment: I had the same problem once, I tried many things and it didnt work out, finally I uninstalled my django installation and install django again using PIP and that seems to fix the issue.

Comment: @IainShelvington In a folder inside STATIC_ROOT. The folder is mention in the path (img) as in the question, and the setup works for all existing files in the exact same folder.

Comment: @ArunT I picked up the project after a fresh install of python and django, so that is probably not the case. I even deleted the __pycache__ folders just to be sure.